# Does mySQL update statement actually update all fields in the background?

Tags: mysql, logging, transactions, server

This might be a simple question that somebody already might have an answer.  When an UPDATE statement for MySQL is sent to the MySQL server even with only specific fields to be updated, does the server actually update all the fields in the row?  We have some issues trying to understand the server transaction log.

Basically I want to understand the inner workings of the MySQL server.  Does it create the record set with all the values and the override the old record set with the new one or does it only pick the specific fields in the records and only update that.

TL;DR:  If each record set is a binary memory section, does the entire memory section get updated even if specific fields of the record is chosen for update?

Comment: is your binary_logging format mixed or row based? run `show variables like 'binlog_format';`

Comment: The binary server logs (I assume you mean these) are written in the format you want. You can choose statement and row based logs. And for rows, you can specify if you want to log full (all columns), minimal (only changed columns, and columns needed to identify rows), and noblob (all columns, except for unneeded BLOB and TEXT columns). Although this has nothing (or not much) to do with the internal storage of the raw data in the table itself, if that is what you are asking about (that can be moved around, copied and cached as needed). What are your issues with the log?

Comment: We are seeing massive update statement that were supposedly coming from Excel VBA ADODB update query.  They were supposed to only update only some fields in the row.  A record has 256 fields and the server log shows that all 256 fields are updated.  We are trying to figure out whether it's the server that execute all the field update or it's Excel generated update statement that generates all the fields to be updated.

Comment: You can check the query log (if you have enabled it). It will show she query as it was sent by the client (in this case excel). I would assume excel will just generate a full query, because otherwise it would have to read the data first. On the other hand, I still don't know what the problem would be. The data will end up to be the same, if all columns of a row get "updated" with identical values or not (unless you don't want excel to change some values, then you might want to intercept them with a trigger). Don't worry about internal storage (like e.g. encryption). Unless I missed a point.

Comment: It turns out the binary-logging format is set to "mixed" and this is the root of the problem.  When MySQL encounter "unsafe" update statements, it generates row-based update instead of the statement based update.  Now we get into the territory of what's considered unsafe.  That's a whole different topic.